# How to print out the first element of a const string?

Tags: c++, constants

How to print out the first element of a const string?

I tried to do std::cout << path[0] << std::endl; on CLion
but path[0] does not work and the IDE would warn.

CLion warns that

> Cannot assign to return value because function 'operator[]' returns a const value.

```
type print(const std::string &path){}
```

Comment: *"but it does not work"*: good to explain, what **exactly** did not work? and what **kind of error message** you are getting, to make your question more clear.

Comment: What warning? What is `type`? What are you not showing?

Comment: Is your string a pointer type?

Comment: @HuangMolly `path[0]` works just fine. Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] that doesn't work for you.

Comment: On the CLion, it warns. I don't know why. Maybe it works on CSIF but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
std::string::at
```

It can be used to extract characters by characters from a given string.

Consider an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
   string str = "goodday";
   cout << str.at(0); 
   return 0;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Considering the subscript operator that the OP used in the question also extracts characters from the string, you should explain why this will work when the code in the question doesn't.

Comment: Thank you.It works. But just wondering why I can use at(0) but not path[0]?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can ignore the warning sometimes the compiler complains about unnecessary things, secondly do not do the following:

```
type print(const std::string &path){}
```

Dangerous, first of all Passing a string as a reference?? Think about it from the compilers point of view, the string is const, each time you use the += you are actually create a new string. But if you use the & with the string you are telling the compiler that you are planning to modify the string object which has type const..... Use string path as a parameter but never, ever use string& path......